# How can I groupby a dataframe and then transpose and rbind groups in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

```
library(dplyr)
sample.df <- data.frame(group.column = c("first_a","first_b","first_c","first_d",
                       "second_a","second_b","second_c","second_d",
                       "third_a","third_b","third_c","third_d"),
           value.column.first = 1:12,
           value.column.second = 13:24)
```

I created a buffer column and I tried the code below but it was no use.

```
sample.df %>% mutate(buffer = `group.column` %>% strsplit(split="_") %>% lapply(function(x) {x[1]}) %>% unlist) %>% group_by(buffer) %>% t %>% rbind
```

I want this table

| A header | a.1 | a.2 | b.1 | b.2 | c.1 | c.2 | d.1 | d.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | 1 | 13 | 2 | 14 | 3 | 15 | 4 | 16 |
| second | 5 | 17 | 6 | 18 | 7 | 19 | 8 | 20 |
| third | 9 | 21 | 10 | 22 | 11 | 23 | 12 | 24 |

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`separate` your group column, and use `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
sample.df %>% 
  separate(group.column, into = c("A header", "name")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(value.column.first, value.column.second),
              names_glue = "{name}.{match(.value, unique(.value))}",
              names_vary = "slowest")

# A tibble: 3 × 9
  `A header`   a.1   a.2   b.1   b.2   c.1   c.2   d.1   d.2
  <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 first          1    13     2    14     3    15     4    16
2 second         5    17     6    18     7    19     8    20
3 third          9    21    10    22    11    23    12    24
```

Explanation:

- `separate` divides the group.column string into two columns, one called `A header` with the first part (first, second, third), and one called `name` with `a, b, c...`. I call it `name` because that's the default value for the `names_from` parameter in `pivot_wider`.
- in `pivot_wider`, names are taken from `name`, and values from the value columns. The names of the column are composed of the `name` value (a, b, c) and `match(.value, unique(.value))` is a way to get the position of each of the 2 `.value` columns. `names_vary = "slowest"` is used to get the column ordering correct.